# singular locus of semi-normal variety

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra

Let X be a seminormal variety and S be the singular locus of X. Is Blow$_S X=$ the normalisation of X?

Is the singular locus given by the conductor ideal?

Comment: That fails for a union of two $2$-planes in $\mathbb{A}^5$ whose intersection equals the origin.

Comment: You can actually take the $2$-planes in $\mathbb{A}^4$ in that example.

Comment: Continuing Jason's counterexample: $\mathrm{Blow}_SX$ contains the blow up of every branch of $X$ through $S$. So $\mathrm{Blow}_SX\to X$ wouldn't even be finite unless $S$ is of codimension $1$. Do you have that in mind? You also might have a better chance with Nash blowing up.

Comment: S is codimension 1

Comment: can you give me some reference where i can get good examples of nash blowup

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, definitely the singular locus is not equal to the conductor.  If $X$ is normal, the singular locus of $X$ is definitely not given by the conductor (which is the unit ideal and doesn't vanish anywhere).

For the first question however, Greco-Traverso actually studied blowing up the *conductor* in a seminormal variety $X$.  For example, they showed the following.

**Theorem**  *Suppose $X$ is an S2 seminormal scheme and $B$ is the conductor.  If the normalization of $X$ is factorial (for example regular), then the normalization is equal to the blowup of the conductor.*

See section 7 of Greco-Traverso's *On seminormal schemes* for this and some slightly more general results.  They also have some references to some other papers where blowing up the conductor is considered, for example Wilson, *On blowing up conductor ideals*